# Is it possible to pull all messages from a RabbitMQ queue at once?

Tags: python-2.7, rabbitmq, pika

I would like to pull messages from a RabbitMQ queue, wrap them in a object and dispatch for some kind of processing. Ofcourse I could iteratively do that until the queue is empty, but I was wondering if there is any other way (some flag of some kind) or a neater way.

Comment: I could not understand what you want to achieve exactly. Could you please elaborate your question?

Comment: @EmreSavcı In other words, I am talking about pulling a batch of messages from the queue at once just like eandersson points out in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ does not support batches of messages, so you do indeed need to consume each message individually.

Maybe an alternative would be to batch the messages yourself by publishing one large message with all the required content.

Comment: Generating a large message with multiple message embedded inside it is not possible in my case as messages arrive in an async manner.  The number of messages too could vary in different queues. I just wanted to optimize over pulling the messages again and again from the queue.